# Detect cubic curve with Hough transform

Tags: computer-vision, hough-transform

I have a picture with a curve which can be defined by the following equation:

```
y = ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d
```

It is obvious how to use the normal Hough transform to detect the curve. However, I want to reduce the parameter space by using the gradient direction (I already got it from edge detection). I am not sure how to use the gradient direction to reduce the parameter space.

An idea I had is to find the derivative dy/dx = 3ax^2 + 2bx + c . Now I have only three parameters hence my task is easier. Is this correct tho? How do I get the d parameter if I use this?

Comment: Are you concerned with speed or processing time? What size is your image? As part of the solution, is it permitted to precompute a look-up table? Can the curve be more then one pixel in width? And would you have an example image you could post?

Comment: Hey..I am not concerned about speed nor processing time. The image could be any size but let's assume for the sake of an example that the image is 256x256. No I cannot compute a look up table and yes the curve would be more than one pixel in width. However, this is just an artificial example..no need to elaborate on the solution. I just need to find out how to incorporate the gradient direction in the algorithm. That's all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After running Hough for  dy/dx = 3x^2 + 2ax + b
you have

c = f(x,y) =  y - x^3 + ax^2 + bx
where a and b are known.

Why not another pass, this time looking only for c?
Two dimensional accumulator, and then 1 dim is better then 3 dimensional accumulator, anyway.

Comment: Ok so I was right that when I run it with dx/dy I can find the two parameters a and b. Hence, I can run it another time for c with a one dimensional accumulator! Is there a smarter way to use the gradient info?

Comment: Well, I'm not sure if gradient you got from edge detect is precise enough to be use this way. But if it is, and if you can get a and b from procedure you described, then you can also extract c. And I think that this 2 step algorithm would be faster then Hough with 3 dim accumulator.